# OCAPI: my question is that ,Is it possible to get save for later or wishlist product using OCAPI for registered user

Tags: demandware

OCAPI: Is it possible to get save for later or wishlist product using OCAPI for registered user.

Comment: I tried now i getting ClientAccessForbiddenException\",\"message\":\"Access to resource 'GET /shop/v17_8/customers/*********/product_lists' is not allowed for the current client.\"}}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create wishlist with:
POST https://hostname:port/dw/shop/v18_8/customers/{customer_id}/product_lists API

Add product: 
POST https://hostname:port/dw/shop/v18_8/customers/{customer_id}/product_lists/{list_id}/items